# Prestashop Customers WebService passwd

Tags: angular, prestashop, md5

I am developing a login from angular and ionic3 against the prestashop webservice. I have access to the web api and the calls are working well.
The problem is that I have searched how to encrypt the password that the user writes against the prestashop and they do not match.

I have read a lot of posts and I know that prestashop's way of working is to encrypt the md5 password and with a password followed by the password.
As:

md5 (_cookier_key_ + userPassword)

I tried to encrypt my password like the previous example (I have _cookier_key_ + my password) the result of the md5 encryption is the following:
f01e5b4d319dba0b6d41ec601d7720fd

But in my prestashop  webapi the same password it show like:
$2y$10$36OeM33DN5zqrKWMnXqgz.RDzVorpZDl3do3UaRuhwDhlXsOh.jwO

What type of encryption generates $ and . ?

I can see that some users of my prestashop have the password formed md5 as:
0367d421dd907a86d980a69dbb033589
but other custommers have passwords like:
$2y$10$I5OGoI4HcqGTyee9W5Hvt.5fu/sJnH8I8dv9UoL38s.v1oqhhGyaO

what is happening?

A thousand thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can se in [Hashing.php](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/src/Core/Crypto/Hashing.php) Prestashop uses bcrypt as password hashing function, so the strings that you see in password column in database are results of apply it.

In order to check if passwords are correct from ionic you must use a bcrypt verifier function. So lets go:

**1- Install [bcryptjs](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js) in your ionic project**

```
npm install bcryptjs --save

npm install @types/bcryptjs --save
```

**2 - Import bcrypt in your .ts file where you are going to check passwords**

```
import * as BcryptJS from "bcryptjs";
```

**3 - Check password:**

Example: $2y$10$pUxl49suKpBXDYzXfDf7x.E2n9xyP7OWKrTs3jWxkX1C/ml10lypK --> string generated by prestashop and stored in database for 'admin' password

```
BcryptJS.compareSync('admin', '$2y$10$pUxl49suKpBXDYzXfDf7x.E2n9xyP7OWKrTs3jWxkX1C/ml10lypK'); // returns true


BcryptJS.compareSync('test', '$2y$10$pUxl49suKpBXDYzXfDf7x.E2n9xyP7OWKrTs3jWxkX1C/ml10lypK'); // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks @alanjs

Actually I had already found the solution but I had not had time to self-answer in case there are more people who find the problem.

In Prestashop, since md5 is no longer safe, there are 2 types of encryption. MD5 and BCrypt. Old users who have not made a password change have their password encrypted with md5 and new ones with BCrypt.

The problem is that I did not have access to the prestashop code and therefore could not see the encryption methods that are being used.

Anyway, thank you very much, the steps you have described are exactly what I found in another post and those that worked.